# jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: index.html

Tags: python, html, flask, browser, server

I try to open a index.html using Flask

`run.py`

```
from app import app
app.run(debug = True)
```

`__init__.py`

```
from flask import Flask  
app = Flask(__name__)
from app import routes
```

`routes.py`

```
from flask import render_template
from app import app
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    user = 'Cala'
    return render_template('index.html', user=user)
```

`index.html`

```
<html>
    <body>
        {% for user in users %}
            <h1>Hola {{ user }}</h1>
            <h1>Bienvenido a Olivanders</h1>
        {% endfor %}
    </body>
</html>
```

When i run the run.py file i have the error `jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: index.html`

The files are in the filed called *app* except the run.py, this filed is in the general filed

[image: Structure directory]

Comment: Because `render_template` is expecting your templates to be in a subdirectory called `templates` by default

Answer (score 6):

Okay, let me elaborate in steps.

Step 1. Create a new folder called "templates"

Step 2. Move your "index.html" in to the "templates" folder

Step 3. In your index function, return render_template('index.html', user=user)

Hope this helps, feel free to ask any questions!

Answer (score 1):

In the app folder, make a folder called templates. Put index. HTML in there. Then do this: 
return render_template('index.html', user=user)

Answer (score 0):

I think the template 'index.html' needs to be within a `./templates/` folder, i.e. `CODIGO/templates/index.html`

Ref- https://kite.com/python/docs/flask.render_template

Comment: I do that and the error is the same, i change the routes.py `return render_template('templates/index.html', user=user)` but not is solved

Comment: Yeah you are supposed to keep the index.html in the templates folder but in the render_template("index.html", user=user)